# Volume inside paraboloid and sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, volume, multiple-integral

> Find the volume inside the paraboloid $az=x^2+y^2$ and inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2a^2$

Since we have $x^2+y^2$ I thought about polar coordinates , but before that I showed the functions as $z_1=\frac {x^2+y^2}{a}$ for the paraboloid and $z_2=\sqrt{2a^2-x^2-y^2}$ and I am not sure if this is a right way to see it but if $x$ and $y$ are close to zero we can then see that the sphere is above.

$\iint z_2(x,y)-z_1(x,y)dA$ should be the integral that is the volume

$\iint(\sqrt{2a^2-x^2-y^2})-(\frac {x^2+y^2}{a})dA$ here it seems like the right choice to go with polar coordinates but I got stuck in this part , $\iint(\sqrt{2a^2-(x^2+y^2)})-(\frac {x^2+y^2}{a})dA$
we know that
\begin{cases}
 x=rcos\theta\\
 y=rsin\theta\\
 r^2=x^2+y^2\\    
tan\theta=\frac{y}{x}
\end{cases}

$\iint_{r\theta}(\sqrt{2a^2-r^2})-(\frac {r^2}{a})rdrd\theta$ according to the way I drew it I think that $\theta$ should be $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$ But I cannot find $r$.

Would appreciate any help and tips , other approaches are always great thank you!

Comment: Hint: The paraboloid $az=x^2+y^2$ and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ intersect along the circle $$x^2+y^2=a^2,z=a$$ Can you show this? Can you write this volume as an iterated triple integral? (I'm assuming here that $a>0$)

Comment: @MatthewPilling Thank you for the quick reply but is there a way without triple integrals? as we haven't learned them yet

Comment: You can first find the volume underneath the surface $z=\sqrt{2a^2-x^2-y^2}$ on the domain $x^2+y^2\leq a^2$, then find the volume underneath $z=\frac{x^2+y^2}{a}$ over the same domain, and then subtract the two results.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I didn't expect it to be this confusing , I am trying but I got no lead on anything.. I was expecting it to be something with polar coordinates as I was taught. Guess I need more practice before approaching this again.

Comment: New math is always confusing at first. Hang in there. The more you think about it the more clear it becomes. The basic idea is very similar to what you do in single variable calculus. Recall that if $f_1(x)<f_2(x)$ on a domain $[a,b]$, then the area between $y=f_1(x)$ and $y=f_2(x)$ on this domain is $$\int_a^b\Big(f_2(x)-f_1(x)\Big)\mathrm{d}x$$ Compare this with the following statement: If $f_1(x,y)<f_2(x,y)$ on some domain $\mathbb{D}$ in the $xy-$plane, then the volume between $z=f_1(x,y)$ and $z=f_2(x,y)$ on this domain is $$\iint_{\mathbb{D}}\Big(f_2(x,y)-f_1(x,y)\Big)\mathrm{d}A$$

Comment: The region of space inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2a^2$ and inside the paraboloid $az=x^2+y^2$ is the same region of space that's *above* $z=\frac{x^2+y^2}{a}$ and *below* $z=\sqrt{2a^2-x^2-y^2}$. When I am tasked to answer such problems, I first always try to envision the region  whose volume I'm computing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection between the sphere and the paraboloid takes place when $2a^2-z^2=az$, that is, when $z=a$. So, if $(x,y,z)$ belongs to the region whose volume we are trying to compute, then:

- if $z\leqslant a$, then $0\leqslant x^2+y^2\leqslant az$;
- if $z\geqslant a$, then $0\leqslant x^2+y^2\leqslant 2a^2-z^2$.

So, compute$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a\int_0^{\sqrt{az}}\rho\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\theta+\int_0^{2\pi}\int_a^{\sqrt2a}\int_0^{\sqrt{2a^2-z^2}}\rho\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\theta\left(=\frac{ \left(8 \sqrt{2}-7\right) \pi  a^3}6\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for the help , but I wonder if there is another way to solve or approach this without triple integrals? as we haven't gotten there yet and can only use double integrals , sorry it is my mistake I didn't mention this

Comment: You can even use a single integral, if you are interested in applying the [disk method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration). Are you?

Comment: that is interesting I don't remember the disk method much ( learned it in a previous course) , but I think that in this question it is about double integrals I am trying to practice it as most of the exam will be on this topic

Comment: Note that in the integral$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a\int_0^{\sqrt{az}}\rho\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\theta$ there is no $\theta$ inside. So, this integral is really just the double integral $2\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a\int_0^{\sqrt{az}}\rho\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm dz$, and the same thing applies to the other integral.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I didn't see the lower bound of "a" on your second integral, my bad. Your order of integration is interesting. In my opinion, a more natural order would be $\mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$ giving us $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a \int_{r^2/a}^{\sqrt{2a^2-r^2}}r\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Comment: Also, to the OP, you can enforce a single variable approach by recognizing that the solid whose volume you're trying to compute is the one formed by rotating the region in the $xz-$plane defined by $$x^2/a \leq z \leq \sqrt{2a^2-x^2}$$ $$-a \leq x \leq a$$ around the $z-$axis.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I think that that order of integration turns out to be more natural than mine.