# Why am I getting a wrong answer ? (volume using triple integrals)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, volume, multiple-integral, spheres

> Find the volume inside the paraboloid $az=x^2+y^2$ and inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2a^2$

I asked this question before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118992/volume-inside-paraboloid-and-sphere) , but now I am trying a different way to solve it and I cannot figure out why it is not working.

What I did:

I checked which of them is above that other , and figured it is the sphere , then I found the intersection point between them which is $2a^2-z^2=az$ , $z=a$.

I tried to solve with sphere coordinates , so I transformed the equations to sphere coordinates and got
$arcos\phi=r^2sin^2\phi cos^2\theta+r^2sin^2\phi sin^2\theta$ , $acos\phi=rsin^2\phi$ (this is for the paraboloid) for the sphere I got $r=\sqrt{2}a$ Then I compared them and got $cos\phi=\sqrt{2}sin^2\phi$
So I need to find $\phi$ at the intersection points what I did was $sin^2\phi=1-cos^2\phi$ , $cos\phi=\sqrt{2}(1-cos^2\phi)$ , $cos\phi-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}cos^2\phi=0$ then after doing $cos\phi=t$ I got $\phi=\frac{\pi}{4} $ and $\phi=\frac{7\pi}{4} $ I only took $\phi=\frac{\pi}{4}$ because as far as I know in sphere coordinates $0\leq\phi\leq\pi$.

After that I have 2 volumes , the first until the paraboloid and the second till the sphere.
so for paraboloid I got $V_P $ \begin{cases}
 0\leq\theta\leq2\pi\\
 \frac{\pi}{4}\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\\
 0\leq r\leq a\\    
\end{cases}
And for sphere $V_S$
\begin{cases}
 0\leq\theta\leq2\pi\\
 0\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{4}\\
 0\leq r\leq \sqrt2a\\    
\end{cases}

After that the integration result is wrong , here is what I did
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{a}r^2\cdot sin\phi\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm d\theta+\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sqrt{2}a}r^2\cdot sin\phi\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm d\theta$$

according to my previous post the answer should be $\left(\frac{ \left(8 \sqrt{2}-7\right) \pi  a^3}6\right).$ while what I got is $\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi a^3}{3}$ + $\frac{4\sqrt{2}\pi a^3-4\pi a^3}{3}$

I am trying to rely on this way because I noticed that my teacher does this a lot , but I am not even sure if it works here? or if what I did is right in someway.

Comment: For one thing, $\phi$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ in spherical coordinates (and $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$).

Comment: @mjqxxxx : First, that depends on whether one is using the physics notation or the mathematical notation (which swap $\theta$ and $\phi$).  Second, this is irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same result with your integral as you write.  (Although it would be easier to compare with the [referenced answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4119003/123905) in the form
$$  \frac{(5 \sqrt{2} - 4)\pi a^3}{3}  \text{.)}  $$

Your integral with $\phi \in [\pi/4, \pi/2]$ has $r \in [0,a]$, suggesting that the lower part of the volume is a ball of radius $a$.  That is, there is a discontinuous jump in the radius at $\phi = \pi/4$ and the radius does not decrease as $\phi$ goes to $\pi/2$.  This is incorrect, the lower part of the volume is bounded by the paraboloid.  Instead, the upper bound for $r$ should smoothly decrease from $\sqrt{2} a$ to $0$.

Consider the slice where $y = 0$.  On this slice, we have the parabola $a z = x^2$, so $\frac{z}{x} = \frac{x}{a}$.  Of course, $\tan (\pi/2 - \phi) = \frac{z}{x}$, so you should be able to get the upper bound on $r$ as a function of $\phi$, easily enough...

---

(Added in response to a comment...)

There are a few ways to get the upper bound on $r$ for the integral with $\phi \in [\pi/4, \pi/2]$.  But first, let's get a picture so we can see what we are doing.  (Step one in "how to solve it": sketch a picture.)  (This picture is shown with $a = 4/3$, but one obtains essentially the same picture, with different (identical) ranges on the three axes, for different choices of $a$.)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This helps us see that the sphere provides the bound on the radius for $\phi$ small and the paraboloid provides the bound on the radius for $\phi$ large.  This is a volume of revolution, so we can take the slice with $y = 0, x \geq 0, z \geq 0$ (equivalently, $\theta = 0, 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$).

Let's introduce $\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, the distance between the projection of a point onto the $xy$-plane parallel to the $z$-axis and the origin (of any coordinate system in use, since the origins are all the same point).  Then your $3$-dimensional radial coordinate satisfies $r^2 = \rho^2 + z^2$.  Since this is a volume of revolution, we get the same diagram for every choice of $\theta$.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The points on the parabola satisfy
$$  a z = \rho^2  \text{.}  $$
One way forward is to divide both sides by $\rho$, obtaining
$$  a \frac{z}{\rho} = \rho  $$
so that
$$  a \tan\left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \phi \right) = \rho  \text{.}  $$
and when continue manipulating to make $r$ appear on the right-hand side.

A different way to proceed is to start by immediately making $r$ appear on the right-hand side:
$$  a z + z^2 = \rho^2 + z^2 = r^2  \text{.}  $$
So now the upper bound on $r$ is $\sqrt{az + z^2}$.  Unfortunately, $z$ is not a variable available to us in the innermost integral.  But $z = r \cos \phi$, so ... \begin{align*}
r^2 &= a z + z^2  \\
   &= ar \cos \phi + r^2 \cos^2 \phi  \text{,}
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
r^2(1 - \cos^2 \phi) - a r \cos \phi &= 0  \text{, and }  \\
r(r(1 - \cos^2 \phi) - a \cos \phi) &= 0  \text{.}  
\end{align*}

The two roots are $r = 0$ and
$$  r = \frac{a \cos \phi}{1 - \cos^2 \phi} [{} = a \cot \phi \csc \phi ] \text{.}  $$
The root $r = 0$ tells us our ray intersects the paraboloid at $r = 0$, giving the lower bound for the $r$ integral.  The upper bound is $a \cos \phi / (1 - \cos^2 \phi)$.

And with this change, replacing the $\phi \in [\pi/4, \pi/2]$ integral with
$$  \int_0^{2\pi} \; \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \; \int_0^{\frac{a \cos \phi}{1 - \cos^2 \phi}} \; r^2 \,\mathrm{d}r \,\mathrm{d}\phi \,\mathrm{d}\theta  $$
produces the same result as does the previous answer you cite.

Comment: That's what I got (eventually) but you explained it better.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers , I am having a hard time understanding what you mean (my fault because of the english) , can you please try to explain what you mean by " there is a discontinuous jump in the radius at ϕ=π/4 and the radius does not decrease as ϕ goes to π/2" . do you mean that with  $ϕ∈[π/4,π/2] r∈[0,a]$ I take the ball as it is lower than the paraboloid ?

Comment: @Adamrk : In your second integral, $r$ ranges from $0$ to $\sqrt{2}a$, meaning that the region that is being integrated is the ball of radius $\sqrt{2}a$.  In your first, $r$ ranges from $0$ to $a$, meaning the region that is being integrated is the ball of radius $a$.  So in your integrals, you have two balls (centered a the origin, of different radii) glued together along the cone $\phi = \pi/4$.  Neither integral is using the paraboloid as the bound.

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you , the mistake is clear now . my problem is I cannot think of a way to get the paraboloid bound , is it possible to get a hint please? no answer just a hint to use to solve the problem

Comment: @Adamrk : I've added a bit more about finding the upper bound on $r$ for that range of $\phi$.  Stop reading as soon as you think you know what the upper bound should be.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that inside $V_P$ the value of $\phi$ ranges from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but the value of $r$ ranges from $0$ to $\sqrt2 a$,
not $a.$
Moreover you do not get *every* combination of $\phi$ and $r$ such that
$\frac{\pi}{4}\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0\leq r\leq \sqrt2 a.$
For example, when $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$ the only possible value of $r$ is $r = 0.$

Since you are integrating over $r$ inside the integration over $\phi,$
find the correct bounds on $r$ for each $\phi$ as a function of $\phi$ and use those as the endpoints of your integral.